# Can i make my WordPress website available offline?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you guys please tell me one thing? I am making a WordPress website with elementor, and I have also converted it into an app using thunkable (just showing web view).
"I want to make i available offline"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

when we install wordpress , local link is generated as shown below :

https://localhost/myblog